# Make Numbers i18n compliance with Javascript

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

How can I make Number system i18n compliance with Javascript. I know we can make Date i18n compliance by calling `toLocaleString()` method of `Date` Object.

Comment: what do you mean specifically by `Measurement` ?

Comment: If you mean `Measurement` by the difference between SI units, CGS, UK or US, Celsius vs Fahrenheit then you may want user to choose.

Comment: And Number system... Most countries uses Arabic numbers, and you will have difficulties to make very large Romantic or Natural language numbers.

Comment: According to my knowledge Major languages like Java, Python does provide support for i18n. I am wondering the same with JavaScript.

Comment: @JaromandaX what about Number compliance with internationalisation?

Comment: what about it? I asked what specifically what you meant by measurement

Comment: Some countries might be using CGS unit where as some others use MKS unit. Is there any way to convert SI units to country specific measurement system? @JaromandaX Apologies for the late reply! But I urgently need solution for Numbers that is why I modified question.